# How to extract a substring from a string in PHP until it reaches a certain character?

Tags: php, substring

I have part of a PHP application which assess a long string input by the user, and extracts a number which always begins 20 characters into the string the user supplies.

The only problem is that I don't know how long the number for each user will be, all I do know is the end of the number is always followed by a double quote (").

How can I use the PHP substring function to extract a substring starting form a specific point, and ending when it hits a double quote?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) to get the first position of `"` from the position 20 on:

```
$pos = strpos($str, '"', 20);
```

That position can then be used to get the substring:

```
if ($pos !== false) {
    // " found after position 20
    $substr = substr($str, 20, $pos-20-1);
}
```

The calculation for the third parameter is necessary as [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) expects the length of the substring and not the end position. Also note that `substr` returns `false` if *needle* cannot be found in *haystack*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nLast = strpos($userString , '"');
substr($userString, 0, $nLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$str = substring($input, 20, strpos($input, '"') - 20);
echo $str;

?>
```

Or something like that etc.

Answer (score 0):

find first occurrence of double quote after 20 chars, substract 19 - that gives you length of desired substring:

```
$dq = strpos($string,'"',19); //19 is index of 20th char
$desired_string = substr($string,19,$dq-19);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to just add on to Gumbo's answer in case you need help with the substring function:

```
$pos = strpos($str, '"', 20);
$substring = substr($str, 20, $pos);
```